# Back Button History: Skipping Page After multiple POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I have a php page with a form that submits to itself. On this same page I have a button that uses a javascript function to go back to the previous page.

My issue is that I want to avoid going back to the same page as it is possible to submit to the form multiple times and I cannot use a link because there are multiple ways to access this page.

Current script function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

... to further clarify I am happy with the way the form is posting multiple times, I just need to fix the back button issue. Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get ?

Comment: I don't really understand how to do whatever it is this page is suggesting.. I am pretty much looking for a javascript function that looks at the history and skips over everything with the current page index and goes to the most recent index with a different value

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<?php
    $previous = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $previous = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['previous']);
    }
?>
<html>
    <form>
        <input id="previous" type="hidden" name="previous" value="<?php echo $previous;?>">
        ...(rest of form)
    </form>
    <a href="<?php echo $previous;?>">BACK BUTTON</a>
</html>



</form>
```